# FullCalendar header buttons stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Last week I started working with FullCalendar.
I had some events being shown and some header buttons working.

Today I was doing some other things, like implementing eventClick, when I noticed that the header buttons were no longer working.  Or it may be that only the top header button is working.  (I can get the Preview button to work, but nothing else.)

I took out all the extra code I had added and have it down to the bare bones:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next today', 
        center: 'title', 
        right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay' 
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset> 
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</fieldset>
```

The calendar shows up, and the buttons are there, but only the Prev button works.

I checked to make sure that all 4 files that FullCalendar requires exist and are being referenced in my code.

All I can think is that I have a syntax error somewhere that I'm not seeing.

Comment: i tried to add your settings to default example of fullpage and all buttons work.

Comment: _"All I can think is that I have a syntax error somewhere that I'm not seeing"_. If you have a syntax error, or some other runtime error, it will be shown in your browser console...did you look there?

Comment: Just double-checked:   NOTHING in the console.   And Cesare is able to get this exact code to run, so I must have some other code interfering.  I guess I'll start the process of commenting things out.

Comment: So this is interesting.  If I change the header so that the order is 'basicWeek, month, basicDay' the calendar comes up in Month View.  I can then click on "Week" to get Week View.  But then I can NOT click on Month again.  Only the top buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is interesting.

If I comment out the link to "fullcalendar.css" style sheet, everything works fine.  Stay tuned...